Inline boots also vary on Shin/ankle diammeter between sizes? Feeling more support in one foot that another with K2 Kinetic 80
I am a complete novice in inline skating, with about 5 hours of practice in total. I am also in my early 40s.
I just got a set of K2 Kinetic 80 boots in size 8 (40.5 Europe). They are better than the first set of cheap €26 skates I started with, but I feel like I get more support on my right foot than my left.
My left leg is a little bit thinner than my right one. When I measure the circumference of them, the right one is about 20.8 cm, while the left is 20 cm.
When I try to go in a straight line with just one foot, using the other to propel me, it works as expected with the right leg. However, on the left, I tend to use the external part of the skate more and feel that my leg jiggles more.
If I put some padding (sponge) on the top, internal part of the left boot, this gets better.
It could be that I tend to put my weight a little on the external part of my left foot, but I am not sure.
I am thinking of trying a smaller size, which theoretically will be the exact same length as my foot. But I am not sure if the upper part of the boot also changes in size between sizes, as I cannot find any measurements online.
That said, I do not know if maybe that is something I am doing wrong and should just try to align my left foot better.
So in summary: Does go down in size will help me with the support I feel i am missing? Or Do I need to train my left foot/leg to keep in "centered"
Thanks!
